# How to submit photos in the website?

Tags: canon-550d, photography-basics

I am new to this website. I saw this contest going on so as I am also a (Beginner) Photographer, I have my own clicked images and I wanted to upload them for the context but don't know how so please help me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This question belongs in Meta.

Comment: should i delete it then?

Comment: A friendly local mod will move it probably.

Comment: for meta its asking for more then 5 reputation...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This question is being migrated to the meta site, so I'm answering as if this is already there.)

You will need 11 reputation to participate in the contest, because that is the threshold at which you can post images. That is a fairly low bar — you just need two upvotes on a question or one upvotes on an answer. The contest is really meant for people who are active on the site, so please do join in and participate in asking and answering questions. You'll meet the requirements in no time at all.

Once you have, simply post an answer to [Weekly Featured Image: Ongoing Contest](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest), making sure to follow the rules (particular about size and about watermarks or borders).

And, welcome!